# How to pass Struct parameter when a Dynamic Method Invoke in C#?

Tags: c#, emit, dynamicmethod

I have trouble with pass struct parameter in dynamic method.
Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var DynamicAssembly = new AssemblyName();
        DynamicAssembly.Name = "DynamicTypes";
        AssemblyBuilder ab = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(DynamicAssembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(DynamicAssembly.Name);
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("Handler", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);
        MethodBuilder handler = tb.DefineMethod($"DynamicHandler",
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
           typeof(void),
           new Type[] { typeof(MyClass), typeof(MyStruct) });
        var ProcessMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Process));
        ILGenerator il = handler.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, ProcessMethod, null);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var DynamicType = tb.CreateType();
        MethodInfo methodInfo = DynamicType.GetMethod("DynamicHandler");
        int i = 100;
        while (true)
        {
            i++;
            MyClass a = new MyClass()
            {
                a = i,
            };
            MyStruct b = new MyStruct()
            {
                b = i,
            };
            methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b });
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
    public static void Process(object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"arg1:{arg1} arg2:{arg2}");
    }
}
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
public class MyClass
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

When I run my code to `Process` method parameter `arg2` found 'FatalExecutionEngineError' cannot read memory.

But if I change my second parameter to `MyStruct` like

```
    public static void Process(object arg1,MyStruct arg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"arg1:{arg1} arg2:{arg2}");
    }
```

It works normal,but It's not what I want.

I think my IL code is not correct,but I don't known where is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `OpCodes.Box` on `MyStruct` in order to pass it as `object` as a parameter to a method.

You also do not need to call `OpCodes.Nop`either.
So basically what your code should be like is→

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(MyStruct));
//Rest is the same
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried just now,but It throw a Exception when the code run to `methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { a, b });`'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException', InnterException is BadImageFormatException: Class labels are incorrect.

Comment: @BigDream It's possibly a x32 - x64 bits mismatch. Please check your projects' target platform and compile them accordingly. As far as I understand since you are using Dynamic assembly, you might as well be using Assembly.Load to load external .dll

Comment: I tried to change project to 'AnyCpu','x86' and 'x64' three patform.It seems no difference between them.It still throw exception like before.

Comment: This is a test project so there is no external .dlls in it.

Comment: @BigDream, My local test code compiles without any problem. Can you give me more insight?

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! I changed `il.Emit(OpCodes.Box);` to `il.Emit(OpCodes.Box,typeof(MyStruct));` and the problem disappear. Thanks again for your patient answer.

Comment: @BigDream My bad! Let me fix it in the answer as well